# What is the best way to receive all current user ActionCable connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I need to monitor user connections and mark user as offline when user closes all tabs in browser.

I suppose, I should check count of user connections in .unsubscribe method and mark user as offline when count of connections will be zero.

But how to receive all connections of current user?
or
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Rails guide has (half of) an example of this here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#example-1-user-appearances

Basically, you create an AppearanceChannel and every user is subscribed to it. Subscribing calls the appear function for the current_user, which can then be broadcast out.

Comment: But what if user will open several tabs, and then close one of them? AppearanceChannel.unsubscribed will be fired, and user will disappear. It's not very useful example( I need to mark user as offline only when he will close all tabs in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

My current solution:

my_channel.rb

```
class MyChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    make_user_online
  end

  def unsubscribed
    make_user_offline
  end

  private

  def make_user_online
    current_user.increment_connections_count
    current_user.online!
  end

  def make_user_offline
    return unless current_user.decrement_connections_count.zero?

    current_user.offline!
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def connections_count
    Redis.current.get(connections_count_key).to_i
  end

  def increment_connections_count
    val = Redis.current.incr(connections_count_key)
    Redis.current.expire(connections_count_key, 60 * 60 * 24)
    val
  end

  def decrement_connections_count
    return 0 if connections_count < 1

    Redis.current.decr(connections_count_key)
  end

  private

  def connections_count_key
    "user:#{id}:connections_count"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue finding a proper answer to that problem.

I am sharing you the solution I found in GoRails resources (https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/online-users-with-actioncable) applied to my problem, I hope it will help someone!

My channel, it uses Redis to store a list of connected user to this specific channel, I use current_user as a identifier in my `connection.rb` file:

```
class xxxChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    add_to_active_users_on_xxx
    stream_from "something_#{params[:xxx_id]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    remove_from_active_users_on_xxx
  end

  private

  def add_to_active_users_on_xxx
    ActionCable.server.pubsub.redis_connection_for_subscriptions.sadd(
      "active_on_xxx_#{params[:xxx_id]}",
      current_user.id
    )
  end

  def remove_from_active_users_on_xxx
    ActionCable.server.pubsub.redis_connection_for_subscriptions.srem(
      "active_on_xxx_#{params[:xxx_id]}",
      current_user.id
    )
  end
end
```

In my User model I have this method that I can call to retrieve all connected user on a specific channel:

```
  def self.active_on_xxx(xxx_id)
    user_ids = ActionCable.server.pubsub.redis_connection_for_subscriptions.smembers("active_on_xxx_#{xxx_id}")

    where(id: user_ids)
  end
```

Hope this helps some people!